# Does disabling QoS result in more bandwidth?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bandwidth, qos

I am using windows 7 x64 professional and was wondering if I disable QoS, will I get a wee bit more bandwidth? Is disabling worth it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QoS is to bandwidth as process priority is to process performance. They're related, but not directly -- they're affected by external factors. If QoS does limit your bandwidth, consider fixing the cause, not QoS.

Answer (score 1):

QoS service is set to manual by default and will run only when an application (generally an audio/video streaming app) needs it. So no, you won't get any more bandwidth in most cases. Check your up/down speed, it should already be at its max. If you think your bandwidth is not enough check your ISP's web site and see if you can afford more.